# EXM $firstname$ token not replaced in email online version

Tags: exm

I use Sitecore 8.2 update 3 with Email Experience Manager 3.4.2 rev. 170713.

I send EXM campaigns using CM server and 1 additional Dedicated Email Delivery server.

I use token `$firstname$` in the email.

When I see the email in the email client, token is replaced correctly.

When I click the link to see the online version of the email, some of the users don't have the `$firstname$` token replaced. They see `Hello $firstname$` in their browsers.

Online version link is `https://CD.SERVER.COM/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=ENCODED` and Sitecore redirects me to `https://CD.SERVER.COM/email-campaign/messages/2017/CORRECT_EMAIL?sc_pd_view=1&ec_eq=PARAMS`.

I suppose that for some reason, contact identifier cannot be decoded from the encoded parameters.

I checked and both CM and DED servers have same `EXM.CryptographicKey` and `EXM.AuthenticationKey` values.

Any idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: Marek, if you create a processor after the decrypt processor in the `<redirectUrl>` pipeline, you can debug the query string that was decrypted and see the contact identifier.  This might help you get a lead on the issue.

Comment: Thanks @PeteNavarra . I'll check if there is anything that may help

Comment: @MarekMusielak, did you find the solution how to replace the token in email online version? I'm experiencing this on my campaigns.

Comment: I'm with @PeteNavarra on this - seems like the user profile isn't being restored into the session correctly.  There's maybe 255 reasons why that could fail but I'd expect something in the logs about it. If you can add a test ASPX page you should be able to navigate to that after opening your email and still have the contact loaded into Sitecore context, which might make it easier to probe and work out whether it's found and loaded the contact correctly.